# $X^*$ with $weak^*$-topology is first category in itself when $X$ is infinite dimensional Fréchet space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, baire-category, weak-topology

I was reading Rudin's Functional Analysis and stuck at the problem in exercise 11 on page 87: **Let $X$ be infinite-dimensional Fréchet space, then $X^*$ with its $weak^*$-topology is of the first category in itself.** Here is my attempt.

Consider the a basic open set at origin corresponding to $\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subseteq X$ of $weak^*$-topology on $X^*$ given by $\{x^*\in X^* : |x^*(x_i)|<\epsilon, \forall i=1,2,..,n\}$. Now let $y\in X$ and consider a particular $weak^*$ nbd $\{x^*\in X^*: |x^*(y)|<1\}$ which contains a basic nbd i.e. for some $x_1,x_2,...,x_n\in X$ and  $\epsilon>0$ we have $$\{x^*\in X^* : |x^*(x_i)|<\epsilon, \forall i=1,2,..,n\}\subseteq \{x^*\in X^*: |x^*(y)|<1\}.$$ Now this implies that if $z^*\in X^*$ and $|z^*(x_i)|=0, \forall x_i$ with $i=1,2,...,n$ then $tz^* \in \{x^*\in X^*: |x^*(y)|<1\}$ for each $t$ in scalar field $\Bbb K$ and this implies $|tz^*(y)|<1, \forall t\in \Bbb K\implies z^*=0$. Now for $x\in X$ defining $f_x:X^*\rightarrow \Bbb K$ by $f_x(\Lambda)=\Lambda(x), \forall \Lambda \in X^*$ we have $$\ker(f_y)\supseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker(f_{x_i})$$ so that $f_y$ can be written as linear combination of $f_{x_i},i=1,2,...,n$ and  this implies $y$ can be written as linear combination of $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$.

Any suggestion or solution will help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a decreasing basic sequence of $0$-neighbourhoods $U_n$ in $X$ (i.e., every $0$-neighbourhood contains some $U_n$, such a sequence exists because $X$ is metrizable). The polars $U_n^\circ$ are weak$^*$-closed with $X^*=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} U_n^\circ$. By your description of the basic weak$^*$ open sets in $X^*$ it is clear that the interior of each $U_n^\circ$ is empty. (A different argument would use Alaoglu's theorem: If $U_n^\circ$ had interior points it would be a compact $0$-neighbourhood in $X^*$, and any topological vector space with a compact $0$-neighbourhood is finite dimensional.)

Comment: Two questions/comments: 1) Where do you use the assumption that $X$ is completely metrizable? 2) In the "different" argument using the Banach-Alaoglu thm, how do you show that $0$ belongs to the weak* interior of $U_n^\circ$? ((2) actually also concerns (1)...). Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Metrizability is used to get a *sequence* of $0$-neighbourhoods such that every $x^*\in X^*$ is contained in a polar $U_n^\circ$ (completeness is not used). The alternative argument is by contradiction: If $X^*$ were of second category, some $U_n^\circ$ (which is closed) would contain interior points and by convexity, then $0$ would be in the interior.

Comment: Thanks, so completeness is not needed, okay. In both arguments it is used that if the interior of some $U_n^\circ$ is not empty, then $0$ is in the interior. That's not clear for me. I think the convexity alone is not enough, I suppose that balancedness of $U_n^\circ$ is also somehow necessary (and to prove that the interior of $U_n^\circ$ is balanced one already needs that $0$ is in this interior...).

Comment: Okay, I think that $0$ belongs to the interior of $U_n^\circ$, because the interior is  symmetric (since assigning to each $x^*\in X^*$ its inverse $-x^*$ is an autohomeomorphism of $(X^*,w^*)$) and convex. The balancedness is not needed.

Comment: You are right. Explicitely, if $V$ is a non-empty open set contained in $U^\circ$ and $x^* \in V$ then $\frac 12 V + \frac 12 (-x^*)$ is contained in $U^\circ$ by convexity and symmetry, and it is an open set containing the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V_n=\{x\in X:d(0,x)<1/n\}$ and  consider polars $$V_{n}^*=\{\Lambda\in X^*:|\Lambda(x)|\le 1(x\in V_n)\}$$
We have $X^*=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty V^*_n$ since each $V_n^*$ is weak*-compact by Banach-Alaoglu. Hence it is enough to assume one of $V^*_n$ has non-empty interior ,

this implies $\exists\{x_1,\cdots,x_k\}\subset X$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\Lambda(x_i)=0~(\forall 1\le i\le k) \implies \Lambda=0~( \forall \Lambda\in X^*)~(1)$$
Since all weak*-continuous linear functional on $X^*$ have form $\Lambda\mapsto \Lambda(x)$ for some $x\in X$, $(1)$ implies that $X^*{}^*$ has finite dimension.

It is enough to prove that $M=\bigcap_{\Lambda\in X^*}\operatorname{Ker}(\Lambda)=\{0\}$ since when this is combined with $X^*{}^*$ has finite dimension implies $X$ has finite dimension.

Suppose that $\exists x\in M$ such that $x\neq 0$ , since $M$ is a closed subspace of a Frechet space $M$ is Frechet and for every continuous linear functional $f$ on a subspace of a locally convex space $Y$ there exists $\Lambda\in Y^*$ such that $\Lambda=f$ on that subspace , this implies $$M^*=\{0\}.$$
$M$ being Frechet , its topology is induced by countable family of semi-norms $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $M$ is complete w.r.t this family.

If $p_n(x)\neq 0$ for some $x\neq 0$ in $M$ and some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then there exists $K>0$ such that $1<Kp_n(x)$ hence if $f(tx)=t$ then $f$ extends to a non-constant continuous linear functional on $M$.

Hence $p_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in M$ and for all $n$.

Since $M$ is complete w.r.t this family of semi-norms every sequence in $M$ converges to $0$ this is impossible unless $M=\{0\}$.

I tried to make it clear that I'm using every part of hypothesis. Hope it helps :)